# scheduled cores ... did not deliver results, all values of the jobs will be affected in parallel::mclapply() in R 4.0.1

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mclapply

I'm using `parallel::mclapply()` with R 4.0.1 and getting the following warning: "*scheduled cores ... did not deliver results, all values of the jobs will be affected*".

Here the result of my investigation: inspecting the function source code, I realized that it happens when the vector `dr` is not all TRUE. This means that for some cores the second condition inside the for loop below (`is.raw(a)`) is never executed. `a` is the value returned by `readChild()`, that if returned raw data at least once, the condition would be verified at least once. So I'm thinking that `readChild()` is returning NULL.

> readChild and readChildren return a raw vector with a "pid" attribute if data were available, an integer vector of length one with the process ID if a child terminated or NULL if the child no longer exists (no children at all for readChildren).

I ask you to validate or reject my conclusions. Finally if true what are the possible reasons?

```
    while (!all(fin)) {
        s <- selectChildren(ac[!fin], -1)
        if (is.null(s)) break # no children -> no hope we get anything (should not happen)
        if (is.integer(s))
            for (ch in s) {
                a <- readChild(ch)
                if (is.integer(a)) {
                    core <- which(cp == a)
                    fin[core] <- TRUE
                } else if (is.raw(a)) {
                    core <- which(cp == attr(a, "pid"))
                    job.res[[core]] <- ijr <- unserialize(a)
                    if (inherits(ijr, "try-error"))
                        has.errors <- c(has.errors, core)
                    dr[core] <- TRUE
                } else if (is.null(a)) {
                    # the child no longer exists (should not happen)
                    core <- which(cp == ch)
                    fin[core] <- TRUE
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would it be possible to include a minimal reproducible example? See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for guidance.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to reproduce the warning message. At the moment I got it only in AWS Sagemaker with a ml.m5.12xlarge instance and a very large amount of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message can occur when the child process dies/crashes, e.g.

```r
> y <- parallel::mclapply(1:2, FUN = function(x) if (x == 1) quit("no") else x)
Warning message:
In parallel::mclapply(1:2, FUN = function(x) if (x == 1) quit("no") else x) :
  scheduled core 1 did not deliver a result, all values of the job will be affected

> str(y)
List of 2
 $ : NULL
 $ : int 2
```

That a child process completely dies is of course not good.  It can happen for several reasons.  My best guess is that you parallelize something that must not be parallelized. Forked processing (=`mclapply()`) is known to be unstable with code that multi-thread, among other things.

For what's it worth, if you use the [future](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/) framework instead (disclaimer: I'm the author), you'll get an error message that is a bit more informative, e.g.

```r
> library(future.apply)
> plan(multicore)

> y <- future_lapply(1:2, FUN = function(x) if (x == 1) quit("no") else x)
Error: Failed to retrieve the result of MulticoreFuture (future_lapply-1) from
the forked worker (on localhost; PID 19959). Post-mortem diagnostic: No process
exists with this PID, i.e. the forked localhost worker is no longer alive.
```

Comment: Is there a way to get a backtrace for either future or mclapply? In either message, it still doesn't tell me, the user, where the code is breaking.

Comment: I don't think it would ever be possible to get the call stack after such a harsh event as the worker crashing.  It's like calling `tools::pskill(Sys.getpid())` in your main R session and then trying to get a traceback.